Flutter WebView tap target dislocated downward on Android
I'm attempting to utilize a webview plugin to display an HTTP website (specifically the login flow from a WebDAV server). However, in every plugin I've tried, when I click a button or link, nothing happens. Interestingly, if I tap slightly lower on the screen, the interactions work as expected. What could be causing this issue?
I am currently using the webview_flutter plugin. Certain HTTPS sites like Google or pub.dev occasionally work but not consistently. Another observation I've made is that when I zoom in on the website, it functions normally. I have attempted to resolve this issue by changing Flutter and Android SDK versions, removing all widgets from the tree except for the WebViewWidget itself, and exploring alternative plugins. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Turns out, it was a plugin's fault, Responsive Framework:
https://github.com/Codelessly/ResponsiveFramework/issues/175
